# Zone statistics with PostGIS Raster

Tags: raster, postgis

I have a vector layer of polygons (40K) and an elevation raster that I imported into PostGIS. I would like to get the average elevation value for each polygon. First, I imported my raster with my console:

```
raster2pgsql -s 2154 -C -I -M "K:\DATA\MNT\altitude.tif" -F -t 100x100 public.altitude_raster| psql -d db -U postgres -p 5432
```

My research led me to the `St_SummaryStats` clause which calculates a set of statistics (min, max, etc.) including my dear average.

```
SELECT  id, (stats).*
from (SELECT id, (ST_SummaryStats(a.rast, 1, true)) as stats
    FROM altitude_raster AS a, delete as b
    WHERE ST_Intersects(b.geom,a.rast)) as foo
order by 1
```

Although the query works, I am looking at some significant differences with the QGIS "Area statistics" tool. Sometimes I am several hundred meters above sea level of difference.

[image]

I also tested the following query which brings me much closer results than on QGIS, but with the appearance of inexplicable null values.

[image]

Was I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Are there NODATA values in your raster?

Comment: According to QGis, no !